# Can you Transpose/Reverse the shape in Tensorflow's placeholder?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

Lets say that my input data, x, has the shape (2000, 2) where 2000 is the number of samples and 2 is the number of features.

So for this input data, I can setup a place holder like this: 
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2], name='features')

My question is, if I transpose my input data, x, so that the shape is now (2, 2000) where 2000 is still the number of samples, how would I change the "shape" parameter in tf.placeholder?

I have tried setting shape=[2, None], but I just get an error. Does the 1st element in the "shape" parameter always have to be "None"?
Here the error I get: "ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`."

```
import tensorflow as tf
# Binary Classifier Implementation

# Training data
x_train = np.transpose(X) #shape=(2, 2000)
y_train = np.hstack((np.zeros((1, 1000)),np.zeros((1, 1000)) + 1)) #shape=(1, 2000)


# Variables
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[2, None], name='features')
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=[1, None], name='labels')
h1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=x, units=50, activation=tf.nn.relu) #one hidden layer with 50 neurons
y = tf.layers.dense(inputs=h1, units=1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid) #one output layer with 1 neuron


# Functions
#loss
cross_entropy = tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy(multi_class_labels=y_, logits=y)
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(cross_entropy)


# Initializer
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(1000):
        sess.run([cross_entropy], feed_dict={x: x_train, y_: y_train})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be having trouble with shape inconsistency, not with transposing or having an undefined dimension size somewhere other than the first dim.
The following things work fine for me:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2])
x_t = tf.transpose(x)
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[2, None])

print(x_t.shape)
>> TensorShape([Dimension(2), Dimension(None)])

print(y.shape)
>> TensorShape([Dimension(2), Dimension(None)])
```

I'm assuming the first dimension might be your batch-size? Are you maybe not being consistent with this or feeding the wrong shaped data?
Or maybe you're trying to manually change the shape of the tensor? (If so then you don't need to. tf takes care of that as apparent in my example).
That's the most one can help without your giving an idea of the error you're getting, a code snippet, or anything more than a vague and general description, but I hope it helps nonetheless.
Good luck!

---

Update due to updated question:
The error you're getting is telling you exactly what the problem is. You can transpose whatever you want, but the `dense` layer specifically cannot accept a tensor for which the *last* dimension is `None`. This makes sense; you have cannot create a fully connected layer without knowing the sizes of the weight matrices for instance.
If you're transposing `x`, then you're saying you have 2000 features (and 2 data-points) and the NN needs to *know* this in order to create the parameters you're going to train.
If you still consider yourself to have 2 features and however-many examples, then you shouldn't be working with a shape of (2, 2000) in the first place!
Try the following:

```
# Training data
x_train = X #shape=(2000, 2)
y_train = np.hstack((np.zeros((1000, 1)),np.zeros((1000, 1)) + 1)) #shape=(2000, 1)


# Variables
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2], name='features')
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=[None, 1], name='labels')
h1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=x, units=50, activation=tf.nn.relu) #one hidden layer with 50 neurons
y = tf.layers.dense(inputs=h1, units=1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid) #one output layer with 1 neuron


# Functions
#loss
cross_entropy = tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy(multi_class_labels=y_, logits=y)
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(cross_entropy)


# Initializer
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(1000):
        sess.run([cross_entropy], feed_dict={x: x_train, y_: y_train})
```

Hope this helps.

---

On a completely different and unrelated note: I hope you know what you're doing when embedding 2 features in a 50 dimensional space that way.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have updated my question with the code. I'm still not quite sure how to fix it. It works just fine if I just use the (2000, 2) format with tf.placeholder shape=[None, 2] instead of the (2, 2000) format with tf.placeholder shape=[2, None].

Comment: Thanks for the help! The reason I was trying to use the (2, 2000) shape for the input data is because that's the convention I've learned through other sources regarding neural networks that didn't make mentions of Tensorflow. I thought I could try and keep the same matrix convention of feature count by sample count, but I guess you have confirmed that this convention is incompatible with Tensorflow.